# iOS: Block Other Domains in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, restriction

So I'm writing my first app, and have a quick question about blocking other domains in UIWebView. I would like to restrict navigation to my website, and my partner website only. So, if there happens to be a link on my site that links to Google, I'd like for a popup message to occur and say "You can't go there!" or something. I'm not sure how to go about this. I've never played with UIWebView before and am pretty new to programming in general. 
Any help is greately appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *host = [request.URL host];
    if ([host isEqualToString:"oralb.com"] || [host isEqualToString:"other.com"]) {
        // Add any of your own domains in the above line
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: BaseURL == "oralb.com" isn't a valid way to define a string or compare strings. You should be using compare: or isEqualToString: or hasPrefix:

Comment: @Wain - Thanks.  Missed that.

Comment: Add a breakpoint right after host is set and then step through.  Make sure host is the right value.  You might need to used a different method besides host.  [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)

Comment: Also, return NO for everything just to make sure nothing will load.

Comment: So I set breakpoints, added a few `NSLog`s to try and troubleshoot and it doesn't seem to work. It keeps me from navigating off or the oralb.com domain, but wont allow other.com to load at all. I added an `NSLog` right above `return NO` then tried clicking the other.com domain link, and the `return NO` fired. It seems like the || is only working on the left side for some reason. Thanks again for your help, do you have any other ideas what might be the issue? By the way, it made me add in an @ after the `isEqualToString:`'s.

Comment: Log the host, you need to ensure that the string you use is a match when using the isEqualToString: method.

Comment: Ah okay, turns out the host for the first didn't have a www., and the second did! You're the man, thanks a lot!

Comment: Would someone kindly explain where to place the above snippet of code? newbie here. Thanks in advance

Comment: It would go where you would use a UIWebViewDelegate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your controller class the delegate of the web view. Then implement this method in the controller:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

In this method you can examine the `request` to see if its `URL` is acceptable. If it is,  `return YES`, if not, show your alert and `return NO`.

To test the domain you can request the `host` from the `URL` of the `request`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Wain! Also, would this still allow me to browse my entire site or only the homepage? Sorry for the beginner questions and thanks a lot!

Comment: If you validate only the host then all pages on that host will be available. You have the whole URL path so you can do more specific filtering if you need to.